# Extracting unknown data from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm writing an iOS loader that loads data from a plist intending to send vertex data, etc. to the GPU via OpenGL. I can easily extract objects of standard types, like strings, integers, etc.

Where I get stumped is when I encounter what appears to be raw data as a dictionary object. The plist is a native file saved by my 3D modeling software, of which I'm not the author, so I don't know how the data was written into this object.

Some things I DO know about the object, it's likely an array of floats, each vertex needs a float value for X, Y, and Z, and there are 26 vertices in the example below.

Here's the actual data object in the plist file:

```
    <key>vertex</key>
    <data>
    AAAAAL8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC/AAAAPwAAAAAAAAA+gAAAvwAA
    AD7ds9cAAAAAPt2z2L8AAAA+f///AAAAAD8AAAC/AAAAsru9LgAA
    AAA+3bPXvwAAAL6AAAEAAAAAPoAAAb8AAAC+3bPXAAAAALM7vS6/
    AAAAvwAAAAAAAAC+gAADvwAAAL7ds9UAAAAAvt2z2L8AAAC+f//9
    AAAAAL8AAAC/AAAAMczeLgAAAAC+3bPYvwAAAD5///0AAAAAvn//
    +L8AAAA+3bPaAAAAAD6AAAA/AAAAPt2z1wAAAAAAAAAAPwAAAD8A
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAD7ds9g/AAAAPn///wAAAAA/
    AAAAPwAAALK7vS4AAAAAPt2z1z8AAAC+gAABAAAAAD6AAAE/AAAA
    vt2z1wAAAACzO70uPwAAAL8AAAAAAAAAvoAAAz8AAAC+3bPVAAAA
    AL7ds9g/AAAAvn///QAAAAC/AAAAPwAAADHM3i4AAAAAvt2z2D8A
    AAA+f//9AAAAAL5///g/AAAAPt2z2gAAAAA=
    </data>
```

Any ideas about how to read this? Here's where I am:

```cpp
// get plist
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cylinder" ofType:@"jas"];
NSDictionary *cheetahFile = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *objectArray = [cheetahFile objectForKey:@"Objects"];
NSDictionary *model = [objectArray objectAtIndex:1];

//get vertex count
GLshort vertCount = [[model valueForKey:@"vertexcount"] intValue];

//All good so far...but...

//get vertex data?... this doesn't work:
NSMutableArray *vertArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[model objectForKey:@"vertex"]];
```

P.S. Sorry in advance if I'm making a rookie mistake. I'm a designer by profession, not a programmer. So talk slow using soothing tones while I eat my crayons. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<data>` part is an encoded `NSData` object. You can do this:

```
NSData *vertexData = model[@"vertex"];
```

What you do with that data is a whole other discussion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a step closer. Yes, what to do with it...that's the real issue.

Comment: `NSData` is just a stream of bytes. It could be anything. You need to find out how the bytes were created and what they represent.

Comment: It really needs to be an array of floats, something else wouldn't make sense in this case.

Comment: If I save the file as Collada XML, the same data is written as:<float_array id="ID103204992-mesh-verts-array" count="78">0.000000 -0.500000 0.000000...</float_array>

Comment: If the data is simply an XML string, then try `NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:vertexData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.

Comment: I'm betting it's not an XML string, but just what's inside the XML tags. Do you know how to coerce it into an array of 78 floats?

Comment: Not without knowing how it was written. There are many ways the array of floats could have been encoded. Is it simply a stream of 4 (or 8) bytes per float? Big or little endian? Or is it an NSArray encoded with an NSKeyedArchiver?

Comment: I'll try to find out. I'd bet it was an NSArray originally. I'll also look into NSKeyedUnarchiver.

Comment: Thanks for your help Maddy. I don't have the rep to give you an up-vote, but I tried. :)

Comment: I did finally read the data correctly, 16 bytes per vertex, the first 12 bytes are floats that also needed to have the order flipped, I skipped the last 4 bytes (for now, doubt if anything I need is there). Anyway it works, thanks again for your help.